# Creating TabBarController application with authentication window

Tags: iphone, objective-c, authentication, uitabbarcontroller

I'm new in Objective-C coding, hence my question,

I'm writing an application that first requires login to server and if successful then it should display TabBarController with several tabs.

I would like to hear your comment about the following design:

I use storyboard with one TabBarController with segue to different tabs (5 tabs).
for the authentication window I created a TableViewController which is *NOT* connected to by segue to anything.

When the application starts in MyAppDelegate, I check if my KeyChain contains credentials. if it does then I set the RootViewController to the TabBarController, else - I set the RootViewController to the TableViewController and display there an Text fields for allowing users to enter credentials.

Then I take the credentials save them to keychain and set the RootViewController to the TabBarController to open the different tabs.

That's it.

What do you think about it?? is it good or there is a better way to handle this case??

Many thanks for the patience reading this :-)